# What is the closest pair problem useful for?

Tags: student-motivation, algorithms

The [closest pair problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closest_pair_of_points_problem) is the famous problem of finding out the closest pair of points given an arbitrary set of points on a plane. This problem has a divide and conquer algorithm and often is used in algorithms classes to illustrate the divide and conquer paradigm.

I also intend to do the same, but I would like to begin with some comments on why this algorithm is useful. Are there any interesting examples I can use here? A google search reveals nothing.

This is for an introductory algorithms course, and the audience is not expected to be an expert on this topic and has a mediocre level of mathematical maturity.

Comment: Introducing neighbors to each other? Picking up stranded people in a disaster?

Answer (score 4):

Rosen, *Discrete Mathematics and its Applications*, Sec. 8.3, says:

> This problem arises in many applications such as determining the
>   closest pair of airplanes in the air space at a particular altitude
>   being managed by an air traffic controller.

Comment: Welcome to CSE Stack Exchange. Great first answer!